# Django decimal SyntaxError: invalid syntax error in views.py file

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I searched the related questions on the web however I couldn't find any answer for me.

I have a model.py like this;

```
 import datetime

 from django.db import models from django.utils import timezone

 class Product(models.Model):
     product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.product_name
```

and I have a views.py like this;

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Product

from decimal import *


def create_new_product(request):
    new_product = Product(
            product_name = 'test',
            product_price = 10.2,

    )
    new_product.save()

    return new_product

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    #some code here#


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    #some code here#
```

After I run the server, I am getting the following error;

```
    product_price = 10.2,
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Basically, I am trying to create a product which will be eventually inserted into the database. Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: I would remove the unnecessary spaces and the second comma, and put it on one line: `new_product = Product(product_name='test', product_price=10.2)`

Comment: I removed 'request' parameter and put single quotes around product_price. I think these changes solved my problem. Now, it works. I will accept any answer with these information. Thank you @kfarnell for your answer